# SAS remove duplicates based on all but one variable / column

Tags: sas, duplicates

In SAS is there a way of removing duplicates based on all but one column?

As far as I'm aware the below is for removing duplicates based on all columns

```
proc sort data=xyz_01 nodupkey out=xyz_02;
by _all_;
run;
```

As the input table has a lot of columns would I have to list all the columns in the by statement ?

Comment: Do you actually need to keep the 1 column you're not including in the sort?  If so, do you have a preference of which value is kept?

Answer (score 1):

one way to do is by using macrovariable

```
   proc sql noprint;
     select name into :cols separated by " "
     from Dictionary.columns
      where upcase(MEMNAME)= "CLASS"
     and upcase(libname) ="SASHELP"  
     and upcase(name) ne "AGE";
```

try %put and see in log is it that order you want your columns to be ordered.

```
 %put &cols;

   proc sort data=sashelp.class nodupkey out=class;
        by &cols;
    run;
```

or simply list the variables as shown below

```
   proc sort data=sashelp.class nodupkey out=class;
     by name sex height weight;
    run;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can Use Nodup or noduprecs option. mention your primary key in by statement.
Ex:
`Proc sort data=<dataset> out=<out> noduprecs;
by <variable>;
run;`

or `Proc sort data=<dataset> out=<out> nodup;
by <variable>;
run;`